# how to map sharepoint mapped resource folder to app_globalResources folder in VS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, localization, resources, sharepoint-2010

how to map sharepoint mapped resource folder to app_globalResources folder in VS 2010 ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapped Resources folder aside, you can add a module, add a resx file to it and set the module's deployment type to "AppGlobalResources" to deploy to App_GlobalResources.

See the "How do I deploy resource files to App_GlobalResources folder ?" section here:
http://blogbaris.blogspot.com/2012/07/localization-with-sharepoint-2010-and.html

Comment: Thank You, this is a solution for anyone has this problem

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no way that directly support mapping of App_GlobalResources folder to SharePoint Resource Folder. But you Still wanted to do it you can rely on post Build action script in the Project Properties page and copy all the resource files to the sharePoint resources folder.